# Covariant derivative of a metric determinant

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors

It is a well-known fact that the covariant derivative of a metric is zero. In a textbook, I found that the covariant derivative of a metric determinant is also zero.
I know 
$$
g_{\alpha \beta;\sigma}=0
$$

So, $g=\det g_{\alpha\beta}$ is a metric determinant. $g_{;\sigma}$ is a covariant derivative of a metric determinant which is equal to an ordinary derivative of $g$.

$$
g_{;\sigma}=g_{,\sigma}=g g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\beta,\sigma}
$$
My question is why this must be zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the determinate of the metric isn't a function - it's a tensor density.

Using the identity
$$\text{ln(det g)=Tr(ln g)}$$

and taking the partial derivative, one can show

$$\frac{1}{\text {det g}}\partial_\sigma\text{det g}=g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\sigma g_{\alpha\beta}$$

$$\partial_\sigma\sqrt{\text{-det g}}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\text{-det g}}\;g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_{\sigma}g_{\alpha\beta}.\;\;(1)$$

Writing the partial derviatives of the metric tensor in terms of the Christoffel symbol

$$\Gamma^{\rho}_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\sigma}(\partial_\alpha g_{\beta\sigma}+\partial_\beta g_{\sigma\alpha}-\partial_\sigma g_{\alpha\beta})$$

and contracting the indices yields

$$\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\sigma g_{\alpha\beta}.\;\;(2)$$

Substituting equation $(2)$ into equation $(1)$

$$\partial_\sigma\sqrt{\text{-det g}} = \sqrt{\text{-det g}}\; \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\sigma\alpha}
$$

and then combining the partial derivative with the Christoffel symbol implies 
$$
\nabla_\sigma\sqrt{\text{-det g}}= \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\text{-det g}}\;g^{\alpha\beta}\nabla_\sigma g_{\alpha\beta}=\;0.
$$

Comment: Thoroughly explained.

Comment: What is the reason to involve the square root?

Comment: Why did not you start from here?$$g_{;\sigma}=g g^{\alpha\beta}g_{\alpha\beta;\sigma}$$